# No valid constructor error in EJB

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jpa, primefaces

Recently I was changing my machine and had to work creating new workspace environment. I am using Eclipse Kepler. My code worked well on my previous machine but I don't know what went wrong and tried recreating workspace again and again as on my previous machine. But when running the web application(Primefaces,JSF,JPA 2.1 EclipseLink 2.5,tomee 7,java 6,mojarra 2.1.6), I get "no valid constructor error" in EJB which is working well on other machines. My error is :

```
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper doGetState
    SEVERE: com.magnus.sessionejb.util.FiscalYrEJB$$LocalBeanProxy; com.magnus.sessionejb.util.FiscalYrEJB$$LocalBeanProxy; no valid constructor
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.magnus.sessionejb.util.FiscalYrEJB$$LocalBeanProxy; com.magnus.sessionejb.util.FiscalYrEJB$$LocalBeanProxy; no valid constructor
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doGetState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:255)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.getState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:198)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:227)
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.magnus.filter.LoginCheckFilter.doFilter(LoginCheckFilter.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My EJB is :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import com.magnus.model.util.FiscalYrModel;
import com.magnus.sessionejb.core.GenericDAO;

@Stateless
@LocalBean

public class FiscalYrEJB extends GenericDAO<FiscalYrModel> implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FiscalYrEJB() {
        super(FiscalYrModel.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public List<FiscalYrModel> listAllFiscalYr(){
        List<FiscalYrModel> fsList = new ArrayList<FiscalYrModel>();
        fsList = findAllWithGivenCondition(FiscalYrModel.FIND_ALL_FISCAL_YR, null);
        return fsList;
    }


    public FiscalYrModel getActiveFsYr(){

        return findOneResult(FiscalYrModel.FIND_ACTIVE_FISCAL_YR, null);
    }
}
```

I don't know what caused this error which is working well on my previous machine. I had added all the required libraries as configured on my previous machine as well as same version of eclipse.
This particular error is only occurring in my newly configured machine.

Comment: Have you define default constructor in `FiscalYrModel` class ? Look at [java.io.InvalidClassException: no valid constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747443/java-io-invalidclassexception-no-valid-constructor)

Comment: No I haven't defined default constructor in 'FiscalYrModel'. It is an Entity class.